# Which norms on vectors can be consistently decomposed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

I need to know which permutation-invariant norms can be consistently decomposed in the sense that for any vector $v = (a,b,c)$ we have that
$$\|(a,b,c)\| = \|(\|(a,b)\|,c)\|.$$

More precisely, let $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i$ be a finite-dimensional
vector, and $\{P_j\}_{j=1}^k$ a partition of the index set $\{i\}_{i=1}^n$
into $k$ subsets, so that $v = \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i \in P_j} v_ie_i$. The
question is then for which norms is it true that for all vectors and partitions
$$
\|v\| = \left\|\sum_{j=1}^k \Bigg\|\sum_{i \in P_j} v_ie_i\Bigg\|e_j\right\|.
$$

It is easy to see that this is true for every $p$-norm, and every other norm that I've tried failed to have this property, so it would be natural to conjecture that $p$-norms are the only consistently decomposable ones.  Just finding a counterexample to this conjecture would be very useful.

Comment: With your actual definition, there are certainly other examples such as $\|(a,b,c)\| = |a|+|c| + 2|b|$, $P_1=\{ 1, 3\}$, $P_2 = \{ 2\}$. But maybe it doesn't really formalize what you actually wanted. You could also ask for this property for *all* partitions, and the $p$ norms satisfy that too, of course.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant to ask for all partitions.

Comment: Google perfectly homogeneous bases.

Comment: I google it. I don't see how it helps with my question. Note that I'm asking about the finite-dimensional case, and I'm not asking about equivalence in the sense of convergence.

Comment: Your reformulation in terms of basis vectors suggests that your equation $\lVert(a, b, c)\rVert = \lVert(\lVert(a, b)\rVert, c)\rVert$, which doesn't seem to make sense for $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ interpreted as a norm on a space of fixed dimension (since the left-hand side as written takes norms of vectors in $k^3$, and the right-hand side of vectors in $k^2$), is actually supposed to be $$\lVert(a, b, c)\rVert = \bigl\lVert(\lVert(a, b, 0)\rVert, \lVert(0, 0, c)\rVert, 0)\bigr\rVert$$ (with $n = 3$, $P_1 = \{1, 2\}$ and $P_2 = \{3\}$).  Is that correct?

Comment: Then Google bohnenblust characterization of ell_p for information.

Comment: Or just look at Theorem 1.b.7 in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri, Classical Banach spaces, volume II

Comment: `LSpice`, from a norm defined on a space of a fixed dimension one can always define a norm for smaller dimensions using your padding-with-zeroes strategy. I was leaving that implicit, as this was just an informal motivation for the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mikhail Ostrovskii, this is exactly what I needed. I'll write up your comment as a proper answer later.

Comment: Actually, this theorem doesn't seem to imply that the $p$-norms are the only decomposable ones, because it needs to assume that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ $|x| \le |y| \Rightarrow \|x\| \le \|y\|$, and I don't think decomposability of the norm implies this property. Still, this is a very good starting point to look for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem by Bohnenblust is not exactly what I wanted, but it's what I need. Adapting its statement, we have

Let $\|\cdot\|:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ be a permutation-invariant norm for $N \ge 3$ such that

- $\|x+y\| = \|(\|x\|,\|y\|)\|$ for all $x,y$ with disjoint support.
- $\|(1,1)\| \neq 1 $.

Then for any rationals $|a|$ and $|b|$ we have that $\|(a,b)\| = (|a|^p + |b|^p)^{\frac1p}$ for some real number $p \ge 1$.

Proof: Let $f$ be such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1) = \|(1,f(n))\|$. We want to show that $f(n+m) = \|(f(m),f(n)\|$. Assume that it holds for some $m$. Then $$f(n+1+m) = \|(f(m),f(n+1)\| = \|(f(m),1,f(n)\| = \|(f(m+1),f(n))\|.$$
Since it holds for $m=1$ by definition, by induction it holds for all $m$. From that it is easy to see that $f(nm) = f(n)f(m)$ and therefore $f(n^k) = f^k(n)$. We also need to show that $f(n)$ is monotonous. This follows from applying the triangle inequality to the identity $$2(f(n),0) = (f(n),1) + (f(n),-1),$$ which implies that $f(n) \le f(n+1)$.

Now let $m,n\ge 2$ be some fixed integers, and $h$ the integer such that for any positive integer $k$
$$m^h \le n^k < m^{h+1}.$$
Using the properties of $f(n)$, it follows that
$$h\log f(m) \le k \log f(n) < (h+1) \log f(m),$$
and elementary manipulations with $h$ and $k$ let us conclude that
$$\frac{\log f(m)}{\log m} = \frac{\log f(n)}{\log n},$$ which means that this fraction is a constant independent of $n$ and different than $0$. Calling this constant $1/p$, we conclude that
$$f(n) = n^\frac1p.$$
Now for any positive rational $m/n$ we have that
$$\|(1,m/n)\| = \frac1n\|(n,m)\| = \frac1n\|(f(n^p),f(m^p)\| = \frac1nf(n^p+m^p) = (1+(m/n)^p)^\frac1p,$$
so by homogeneity $\|(a,b)\| = (|a|^p + |b|^p)^{\frac1p}$ for any rationals $|a|$ and $|b|$. I guess I can't extend this for all reals without some continuity condition.

Comment: Where are your norms defined? In an arbitrary normed space, permutation-invariance of the norm, or disjointness of the supports of vectors, just don't make sense. And perhaps you are considering some family of norms on different spaces without saying so?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't make any sense, so that's why I'm not talking about an arbitrary normed space. I thought the question already made clear that I'm talking about a fixed norm in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: But then you cannot, as in your answer, insert $1^{(n)}$ for different $n$.

Comment: Sure I can. I'm using the convention that e.g. $\|(a,b)\| := \|(a,b,0)\|$. Just pad the vectors with zeroes.

Comment: Then we must have $n=3$, and you can't insert $1^{(4)}$.

Comment: "e.g." means "for example". But no, you cannot insert $1^{(4)}$ if you're talking about norms in $\mathbb R^3$. Why would you?

Comment: On a second thought, the proof did require me to consider $\|1^{(n)}\|$ for all $n$, so it was incorrect. I rewrote it so that it now applies for all dimensions larger or equal to $3$. Thanks for the heads-up.